# Easy way for mapping data models to domain models

Tags: java, android, kotlin, clean-architecture

I'm following the `Clean Architecture` pattern in which we have the 3 layers (`Presentation`, `Domain`, `Data`).

Every layer should have its own model and these models should be converted when they are passed to another layer using a mapper.

I wanted to know if there is an easy way (a library?) to map a `data model` to a `domain model` without creating a `mapper`, specially if my `data model` has a lot of fields (like 40-50).

**Edit**

I already tried [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) and [DozerMapper](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer) but apparently they don't work well on Android ([ModelMapper issue](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/87) and [DozerMapper issue](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/252)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer, yes there is. Please specify a language.

Comment: @AdamVincent old good Java, but feel free to provide a solution for Kotlin as well (will be useful in the future)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Adam Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7512742/adam-vincent) says, in clean architecture the domain model is central, and beyond that each layer should define it's own model only where it is necessary.

My day job involves multiple projects that use clean architecture.  We generally find that auto-mapping tools are don't provide much value.  The reason is, clean architecture is fundamentally about eliminating dependencies from your domain layer to implementation/intrastructural layers.  Auto-mapper tools tend to support limited transformations, or even enforce that your persistence layer models (e.g. DTO) match domain types 1-to-1.  This tends to limit the ability of the domain and the persistence layer model to be tailored for their distinct responsiblities.

In particular, domain classes very often contain a subtly different set of fields to the corresponding persistence layer classes.  We prefer to use patterns such as immutable clases, constructors, and manually implemented mapping logic (the former greatly simplify maintenance of the latter).  This ensures that transformations between domain and persistance models are explicitly and carefully considered.

Comment: This is a very old question and I actually ended up doing as you said.
I completely agree with the answer and I marked it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks, I hope others find it useful.